# Как переменную из одного js файла добавить в массив, находящийся в другом js-файле?

Tags: javascript, node.js, файлы, global-variables

Кто знает, как переменную из одного js файла добавить в массив, находящийся в другом js-файле?

Comment: А что вы уже пытались сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файл (script1.js), из которого нужно вытащить переменную:

```
let a = 2;
module.exports = a;
```

Файл (script2.js), в котором нужно получить переменную:

```
let a = require('./script1.js');
let arr = [];
arr.push(a);
```